# could not be able to get image from url and set to image view in flex

Tags: flex4.5, e4x, yahoo-api

Any body help me I want to get image from yahoo weather rss and set the source of my  flex component, I'm now able get other data from yahoo weather rss but still not able to get image please help me I have got other data in this way [could-not-be-able-to-get-data-from-yahoo-weather-rss-in-flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759201/could-not-be-able-to-use-yahoo-weather-api-in-flex-mobile-app)

please give me some hint to get that images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, at last today I got idea about how to set image, not about get image, from yahoo weather api or rss feed. So, I tried to get code of condition and set my own image placed in my assets folder like this:

```
            var codeOfCondition:XMLList = result_weather_data_xml.descendants().attribute("code");
```

and then tried :

```
if(codeOfCondition == 0){image.source = "assets/CORRESPONDING_IMAGE_TO_CODE";// for all conditions there should be corresponding image}
```

and this solves the problem for me, there may be some other way to do that but this is my approach thanks.